# Using TypeScript generator/yield with Express would not return data

Tags: typescript, express, generator

I am trying adopt ES6 generator in Express JS along with TypeScript, but with the implementation I have as below, the response does not seem to send anything back, and I wonder what I am missing:

**Main.ts**

```
import * as routes from "./routes";

app = express();
app.use("/", routes);
```

**Routes.ts**

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction, Router } from "express";
import * as Test from "./test";

const routes: Router = Router();

routes.get( "/*", ( req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction ) => {
  console.log( "url", req.originalUrl );
  next();
} );

// Test
routes.get( "/test/ajax", Test.ajax );

export = routes;
```

**Test.ts file**

```
export function *ajax(req: Request, res: Response) {
    const html: string = yield getHtml("http://www.wagamatic.com");
    res.send({
        length: html.length
    });
}

function getHtml(url: string): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise<string>((resolve) => {
        axios.get(url).then((res) => {
           resolve( <string>res.data );
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, when `ajax` function is called, it will simply return a created generator - it will not handle the request. Put a `console.log` in the body of the `ajax` function and make a request - you will see that your `console.log` will not be called. Also, try something like `console.log(ajax())` - you will see the return value is a generator object.

I would propose to you to use `async/await` in Typescript, like that:

```
export async function ajax(req: Request, res: Response) {
    const html: string = await getHtml("http://www.wagamatic.com");
    res.send({
        length: html.length
    });
}
```

If you want to get the generator thing running, you might either use some module like `co`, or write an async executor yourself. [Here](https://github.com/KonstantinSimeonov/terrible-things-with-javascript/blob/master/generators/async-await.js) you can find a minimalistic example of how to do it yourself in node. I would still recommend you stick to `async/await`.

Comment: I have tried async/await and it works like a charm.  I initially opt'ed for Generator/yield approach because it is more testable compared to async/await approach.

Comment: They're almost identical, so I don't really believe there is much difference in testability. The only thing that a generator might be able to do that `async/await` could not is maybe output the values of the async operations waited on with `yield`. In practice, I believe tests relying on this would be changed unpleasantly often.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how yield works. You are basically use it as async/await which is something I do recommend, as it is much more user friendly.

Usually I would write how to fix the problem, but you do not have single usage of yield correct. Look to this page and first try to play with it a bit (or start using async/await): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield